# Gradient of Function of Complex Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, optimization, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent

Consider the following function:

$$ f(T) = \| T^{T}TB - C\|^2_2 $$

where $T, B, $ and $C$ are all complex matrices. Let $T = X + iY.$ I wish to compute $\nabla f$ i.e. $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial T}$. According to the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), for a complex matrix $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial T} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial Re(T)} + i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial Im(T)} \equiv \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial X} + i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial Y}$$

Expanding $f$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$,

$$ f(X+iY)= \| (X + iY)^T(X + iY)B - C\|^2_2 = \| (X^TX -Y^TY+i(X^TY + Y^TX))B - C\|^2_2$$

The Matrix Cookbook also gives that

$$\frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial X} = \frac{Tr((\frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U})^T \partial U)}{\partial X} + \frac{Tr((\frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U^*})^T \partial U^*)}{\partial X}$$

My confusion is in the notation, where $\partial U$ is multiplied by the trace -- I cannot seem to understand what this is supposed to mean. Is it equivalent to $\frac{Tr((\frac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U})^T)\partial U}{\partial X}?$

If so, $U = (X + iY)^T(X + iY)B - C$ and $g(U) = \| U\|^2_2$. Then, $\dfrac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U} = 2U$, $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial X}= B^T(2X + i(Y + Y^T))$, $\dfrac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U^*} = 2U^T$, and $\dfrac{\partial U^*}{\partial X}= B^T(2X - i(Y + Y^T))$.

Therefore, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial X} = Tr(2((X + iY)^T(X + iY)B - C))(B^T(2X + i(Y + Y^T))) + Tr(2((X + iY)^T(X + iY)B - C))(B^T(2X - i(Y + Y^T)))$.

Similarly for $Y$, $\dfrac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U} = 2U$, $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial Y}= B^T(-2Y + i(X + X^T))$, $\dfrac{\partial g(U)}{\partial U^*} = 2U^T$, and $\dfrac{\partial U^*}{\partial Y}= B^T(-2Y - i(X + X^T))$.

Therefore, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial Y} = Tr(2((X + iY)^T(X + iY)B - C))(B^T(-2Y + i(X + X^T))) + Tr(2((X + iY)^T(X + iY)B - C))(B^T(-2Y - i(X + X^T)))$.

Would the gradient computed with this method be applicable for a gradient descent algorithm (like ISTA) for $T$?

Comment: Did you mean to use the hermitian conjugate $T^{H}T$ instead of the transpose $T^{T}T\,$?

Comment: No, the product $T^TT$ is related to transpose symmetry in optics, which is the context of this question.

Comment: In a Wirtinger sense, the gradient wrt $T$ is
$${G \;=\; TB(T^TTB-C)^H\;+\;T(T^TTB-C)^*B^T}$$
The gradient wrt $T^*$ is $G^*$ and wrt $T^H$ it's $G^H$ (the hermitian conjugate). For a gradient descent method, you only need the gradient wrt $T\;$

Answer (score 0):

The [Wirtinger](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282646505_The_Wirtinger_partial_derivatives_no_need_for_the_independence_of_a_variable_and_its_conjugate) gradient of the objective function wrt $T$ is
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\grad fT = G \;=\; TB(T^TTB-C)^H\,+\,T(T^TTB-C)^*B^T \\
}$$
which can be used to calculate the gradient wrt the real and imaginary parts of $T$
$$\eqalign{
T &= X+iY \\
dT &= dX+i\,dY \qiq dT^* = dX-i\,dY \\
df
 &= (G:dT) \;+\; (G^*:dT^*) \\
 &= (G:dX + iG:dY) \;+\; (G^*:dX - iG^*:dY) \\
 &= (G+G^*):dX \quad+\quad i\,(G-G^*):dY \\
 &= 2\,{\sf Real}(G):dX \quad-\quad 2\,{\sf Imag}(G):dY \\
\grad fX &= 2\,{\sf Real}(G),\qquad\grad fY = -2\,{\sf Imag}(G) \\
}$$
This result is consistent with the canonical
[Wirtinger definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_one_complex_variable), i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\grad fT
 &= \frac12 \left(
\grad fX - i\,\grad fY
\right)
  \;=\; {\sf Real}(G) + i\,{\sf Imag}(G)
  \;\equiv\; G
}$$
While it's nice to know how to do such calculations correctly, for gradient descent iterations you really only need the gradient wrt $T$
$${
T_{k+1} \,=\, T_k - \lambda_k G_k
}$$